# can I apply for a Dutch Passport based on my family being Dutch

Tags: netherlands

Both my grandparents were born in Holland . My father was born on the island of Java and then went back to Holland . In 1940 they moved to South Africa and lived their lives here . Can I apply for Dutch citizenship ? I was born in South Africa and am not certain when my father nationalized ..

Comment: You will need to find out whether your father nationalised before you were born. Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/acquiring-dutch-nationality

Comment: If your father naturalized independently of his parents before he was 21, or if he naturalized after your birth, you were Dutch at birth. But if you are 28 or older, chances are very high that even if you were Dutch when you were born, you lost your Dutch nationality under the ten-year rule.  There are some limited exceptions to that rule based on where you lived and who you or your spouse were working for.