# Netherlands passport application

Tags: netherlands

I want to apply for a Dutch passport but I am not sure if I qualify. I was born in 1967 in SA after my mom moved to South Africa and married a South African man. My mom was born in Haarlem in 1944. She never renewed her Dutch passport when she moved to Sout Africa and got married. Do I qualify?

Comment: Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/acquiring-dutch-nationality

Comment: In 1967 you could only inherit Dutch nationality from your mother if she was unmarried.  I believe this makes you "latent Dutch" and might qualify you for the option procedure, but I don't have the details committed to memory and I don't have time to look them up just now.  I'll post later if nobody else does.

Answer (score 1):

As @phoog said in the comments, if you were born before 1 January 1985 to a Dutch mother and a non-Dutch father, you can apply for Dutch nationality via an option statement. You can find all the requirements [here](https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/living-working/becoming-a-dutch-citizen/option-procedure). It's laid out quite clearly by the Dutch government. You can submit your application in person at the Dutch embassy or consulate-general in the region where you live.

Comment: +1, but this does not apply if the parents were unmarried.