# Dutch Nationality

Tags: eu, citizenship, netherlands, eu-citizens, dual-citizenship

Hi i am a 23 year old male (born in 1996) i was hoping that you guys might be able to shed some light on my situation.

My father was born in the Netherlands and moved to South Africa at the age of 8, he did renew his passports for a while, but it expired before i turned 18, along with that the embassy destroyed my passport, when i went to renew.

i was just wondering what my status is as a dutch citizen or national, and do i have ground to renew my passport or atleast get a new one.

ps i am the youngest of 3 and both my older brothers renewed their passports as they were at that time majors and are still citizens.

Comment: Dutch nationality is complicated. You might review this: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/acquiring-dutch-nationality and, in addition, use the search box at the top of the page to search for "Dutch Nationality."

Comment: When was your father born?  When did the embassy destroy your passport?  What did they say about it then?  I suspect that your father lost his Dutch nationality sometime between your birth and your 18th birthday, which probably caused you to lose your Dutch nationality at that point.  The rules changed on 1 Apr 2003, so the details depend somewhat on the timing.