# Am I eligible for a Dutch passport, born in South Africa to a Dutch Father

Tags: citizenship, netherlands, south-african-citizens

Am I eligible for a Dutch Passport? I have done extensive research and cannot seem to find a clear answer. My Dutch father and Dutch grandparents immigrated to South Africa in 1968 from Netherlands. I am the first generation living in SA. My grandmother and grandfather remained Dutch all their lives, both returning to Netherlands. My father was born in Holland on the 03/08/1962, married my South African mother on the 07/01/1997. My mother was born on the 28/09/1960. I was born on the 09/08/1997. My fathers father was born on the 07/10/1934. Any guidance on this would really be appreciated.

Comment: Did your father naturalize in South Africa?  If so, when?

Comment: Do you meet the criteria for any of the ways of acquiring Dutch citizenship listed [here](https://www.government.nl/topics/dutch-citizenship/becoming-a-dutch-citizen)? See related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/acquiring-dutch-nationality